# how do i go back to my system python using pyenv in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyenv

i installed pyenv and switched to python 3.6.9 (using pyenv global 3.6.9). How do i go back to my system python? Running pyenv global system didnt work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your system Python might be `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3`. You have a couple options:

1. Execute that Python interpreter directly:

```
/usr/bin/python --version
```

If you want to run it from a script and you're on a *nix machine, put

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the top of the file, then give it execute permissions (`chmod +x my-script.py`) and run it directly: `./my-script.py`.

2. Turn off pyenv's path hacks. This could mean removing the `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` from your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile and loading a new shell.
3. Use the pyenv register plugin - https://github.com/doloopwhile/pyenv-register (or use/build something similar). Here's a portion of the README

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/doloopwhile/pyenv-register.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-register  # clone plugin
exec "$SHELL"  # reload shell
```

Usage:

```
pyenv register /usr/bin/python
pyenv versions
```

Answer (score 5):

You can "unset" the local pyenv version for your project using the following command:

```
pyenv local --unset
```

Answer (score 2):

`pyenv` sets the `python` used according to `~/.pyenv/version`. For a temporary fix, you can write `system` in it. Afterwards, you'll need to fiddle through your `~/.*rc` files and make sure `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` is called after any changes to `PATH` made by other programs (such as `zsh`).